# For some $\alpha>0$, $ e^L=P\left(\exp(\alpha\sup_{|s-t|\le\delta}\frac{|B_s-B_t|^2}{|s-t|})<\infty\right) $?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am reading one lecture note [Dynamics for Spherical Models of Spin-Glass and Aging](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-40908-3_5) by Alice Guionnet. On page 124, it says that
for some $\alpha>0$,
$$
e^L=P\left(\exp(\alpha\sup_{|s-t|\le\delta}\frac{|B_s-B_t|^2}{|s-t|})<\infty\right)
$$
Moreover, how to show that
$$
E\left[\exp(\alpha\sup_{|s-t|<\delta}\frac{|B_s-B_t|^2}{|s-t|})\right]\le e^L
$$

---

I do not know what is $L$ here. I check the the reference and found that
I just found a useful result: for $\alpha-$Holder continuity Brownian motion, there exists $C=C(\alpha)>0$ s.t. $0<\epsilon\le 1$,
$$
-C\epsilon^{-\frac{2}{1-2\alpha}}\le \log P(\sup_{|s-t|<\delta}\frac{|B_s-B_t|}{|s-t|^\alpha}\le \epsilon)\le -C^{-1}\epsilon^{-\frac{2}{1-2\alpha}}
$$

Comment: Did you look in the recommended reference 28. Ledoux M.; Isoperimetry and Gaussian analysis, Lectures on probability theory
and statistics. Lectures from the 24th Saint-Flour Summer School held July
7–23, 1994. Edited by P. Bernard. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1648. Springer
Heidelberg Newyork, Berlin, (165–294), 1996

Comment: @YuvalPeres Yes, I wrote the result in my question from this reference. But this one I found might not be what I wanted, because if $\alpha= 1/2$, this one doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a typo there - should be E instead of P, as in the second display in your question. Second, the argument as written is not quite right, but it can be rescued. Indeed, $\sup_{t<\delta} (B_t/\sqrt{t})=\infty$, and therefore that expectation is $\infty$. The solution is not to divide by $|t-s|$ but rather by $|t-s|^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$ close to $1$- then the expectation will be finite (using arguments from [28] to control the mean of the sup, and Borel's lemma to control the deviations). The only difference is that instead of $1/M\delta$ you will have $1/M\delta^\alpha$, which is still fine for the rest of the argument.